# generate sql using HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I would like to ask is there any config that allow HeidiSQL to generate INSERT query that look like:

```
INSERT INTO state SET ST_ID = NULL, ST_NAME = "lol"
```

instead of:

```
INSERT INTO state (ST_ID, ST_NAME) VALUES (NULL, 'lol')
```

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

```
1. Select a table in heidi
2. In the query tab, select desired column from the right panel.
3. Right click on the selected column and select 'Generate Update..'
4. In the generated query, change the 'UPDATE' command to 'INSERT INTO'.
5. Delete the 'WHERE' command
```

Answer (score 5):

Ah ok, even that is a feature in Heidi:

1. Double click a table
2. Go to the query tab
3. Expand the "Columns in [table]" tree node
4. a. Right click one column and click "Generate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE"

   b. or select more columns and then right click. The generated query will use selected columns

as picked from  http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=9412